# PHP/Gettext Problems

Tags: php, locale, gettext, zend-translate, setlocale

I remember running some tests a some months ago with gettext and the following code worked perfectly:

```
putenv('LANG=l33t');
putenv('LANGUAGE=l33t');
putenv('LC_MESSAGES=l33t');

if (defined('LC_MESSAGES')) // available if PHP was compiled with libintl
{
    setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, 'l33t');
}

else
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'l33t');
}

bindtextdomain('default', './locale'); // ./locale/l33t/LC_MESSAGES/default.mo
bind_textdomain_codeset('default', 'UTF-8');
textdomain('default');

echo _('Hello World!'); // h3110 w0r1d!
```

This worked perfectly (under Windows XP and CentOS if I remember correctly), which was good because I could use *arbitrary* "locales", without having to bother if they were installed on the system or not. However, this doesn't seem to work anymore, I wonder why...

---

#### Red Hat + PHP 5.2.11:

I'm able to switch back and forth from various locales and the translations show up correclty as long as the `setlocale()` call doesn't return false (if the locale is available/installed on the system).

This is not perfect (would be great if I could just point gettext to any arbitrary translation directory without having to test for the existence of the locale), but it's acceptable. I'll run some more tests later on.

#### Windows 7 + PHP 5.3.1 (XAMPP):

`setlocale()` always returns false (even when using `LC_ALL` instead of `LC_MESSAGES`), unless I use some valid Windows locale such as `eng`, `deu` or `ptg` - in this case the locale seems to be correctly set but the translations still don't show up. I can't test right now because I've hundreds of tabs open but I think the very first call to that script yields the correct translation (restarting Apache won't do the trick).

I'm not sure if this is related to the [PHP Bug #49349](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49349). I'll test this is a couple of hours.

---

Is there any way to use the gettext extension (not pure PHP implementations like [php-gettext](https://launchpad.net/php-gettext/) or the [Zend Translate Adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.adapter.html)) reliably across different operating systems (possibly with *custom* locales like `l33t`)?

Also, is it absolutely necessary to use `setlocale(LC_ALL, ...)`? I would preffer leaving the `TIME`, `NUMERIC` and `MONETARY` (specially) locale settings untouched (defaulting to the `POSIX` locale).

---

I had an idea... Would it be possible to call `setlocale()` with a very common locale (like `C`, `POSIX` or `en_US`) and specify the language via the domain? Something like this:

```
/lang/C/LC_MESSAGES/domain.pt.mo
/lang/C/LC_MESSAGES/domain.de.mo
/lang/C/LC_MESSAGES/domain.en.mo
/lang/C/LC_MESSAGES/domain2.pt.mo
/lang/C/LC_MESSAGES/domain2.de.mo
/lang/C/LC_MESSAGES/domain2.en.mo
```

Would this work on *nix and Windows plataforms without problems?

Comment: Similar Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870320/i18n-gettext-setlocale-configuration-in-web-applications

Comment: This is why I *frigging hate* gettext. It would be so easy if not for this horrible, horrible, unnecessary chaos. Interested to see whether anything comes up.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm using `Zend_Locale` - it can deal with gettext files, too.

Comment: @Pekka: Yeah, I wonder what reliable solutions were available before ZF. Do you use `Zend_Locale` alone or in conjunction with `Zend_Translate`?

Comment: @Alix sorry, I meant `Zend_Translate` here. Yup, that's what I use.

Comment: @Alix see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620670/i18n-with-gettext-but-without-the-locale-hassle that question made me use Zend.

Comment: @Pekka: I've read every single question on SO regarding PHP and Gettext, that's why I had so many tabs opened - in fact I even answered your question (it worked back then!). This question has been getting very little views, I'll probably wait 2 days and start a bounty. I still believe there must be a reliable way to use the native gettext extension, after all it has been shipped with PHP since 4.2.0, long before ZF and even the framework hype... It's a shame that we have to depend on the locale, it would be so much easier if we could tell gettext: "the translations are *here*, use'em".

Comment: @Alix true. It's a simple enough task. Interested to see what comes up!

Comment: @Pekka: I just had a crazy idea: `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'C'); bindtextdomain('default', './locale/l33t/C');`, I wonder if it'll work.

Comment: @Alix Axel: I liked your crazy idea. I tried and it works, BUT not on Windows multithreaded PHP. Again, bindtextdomain() is process wide and still breaks the translation engine. Nice attempt. We need a way to override locale per PHP instance, or a simple parameter to override locale in gettext library.

Comment: @Ghigo: Awww... Someone ought to make a locale independent version of gettext, implemented as PHP extension.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Gettext isn't overly practical for webapps.

- As for example it doesn't honor/use Accept-Language style preferences by itself.
- Typically incurs some caching issues on shared webhosts (mod_php SAPI).

So I sort of sometimes wish that PHP module wouldn't exist, and the convenient `_()` function name shortcut was available to userland implementations.
(Had my own [gettext.php](http://include-once.org/p/upgradephp/), which worked more reliable.)

Your options:

1. Anway, according to a few bug reports the Windows port of gettext had some flaws with UTF-8. Maybe your version is affected again. So try `bind_textdomain_codeset('default', 'ISO-8859-1');` for starters. Also, it seems to prefer the environment variables on Windows IIRC, so `putenv("LC_ALL", "fr_FR");` might work better than `setlocale()`. Especially workable if you dl(gettext.dll) later on.

   Also give it a chance with including a charset right there `LANG=en_GB.ISO-8859-1`. (Since your source text is English anyway, caring about the charset isn't very relavant here; but probably a common case where gettext trips over itself.) Oh and on occasion it's UTF8 not UTF-8; also try ASCII.
2. Alternatively circumvent gettext. Your domain idea is close, but I'd simply use a pre-defined ./locale/ subdir for languages:

   ```
   ./lang/en/locale/C/LC_MESSAGES/domain.mo
   ```

   Then just invoke `bindtextdomain("default", "./lang/{$APP_LANG}/locale")` without giving gettext room to interpret much. It will always look up /C/, but the correct locale directory has been injected already. But try to have a symlink from the $LANG to /C/ in there anyway.
3. Bite in the gnu. Give up on gettext. "PhpWiki" had a custom awk conversion script. It transforms .po files into .php array scripts (yeah very oldschool), and just utilizes a __() function instead. Close. And more reliable.

Comment: Can't test (where's my VM??), but IIRC yes. The C locale is the only hardcoded builtin, so shouldn't be hampered by configuration quirks. http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/gettext/gettext-runtime/intl/localename.c?revision=1.24&root=gettext&view=markup

Comment: The blame is with PHP not `gettext`, you can attempt to use the ICU module to parse `HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING` yet PHP neuters the usefulness of API: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5788824/175849

Comment: @TimoHuovinen Thanks for the hint! (Probably broke aeons ago…)

Comment: np, also that upgrade.php thing is really neat, great work!

Answer (score 6):

This code won't run perfectly on every system, because every systems locale repository + php version is different, among other things.

If you want consistency you need to use something like Zend_Translate, which if you install Zend on each system ( the same version of it ) they would all be consistent with one another because they're using the same localization data, locale names and codebase.

There are numerous bugs with `setlocale`, it's just not reliable. See the comments @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: I'm sorry, I was hurry. After a close read it seems that the `setlocale` is really terrible. Is there a way of take back the down vote?