# How to use Locale::acceptFromHttp without a filter list?

Tags: php, localization, icu

`locale_accept_from_http` is a basic wrapper around ICU's API [`uloc_acceptLanguageFromHTTP`](http://eckhart.stderr.org/doc/icu-doc/html/uloc_8h.html#ced06018568333e1906ae104ab62757a) but the PHP/PECL implementation seems fundamentally flawed that it uses the systems entire set of locales instead of taking a list as a parameter?

For example say a user has `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE =  zh-HK;q=0.2, fr`, i.e. the user reads Traditional Chinese or French, preferring the latter.  You have, for example, a news site that offers articles in say Traditional Chinese and Simplified Chinese.  Using the API 
`Locale::acceptFromHttp` will only return `fr`.

```
<?php
var_dump (Locale::acceptFromHttp ("zh-HK;q=0.2,fr"));
?>
```

Outputs:

```
string(2) "fr"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct, PHP wraps ICU's `uloc_acceptLanguageFromHTTP` without the ability to pass your locale list. Overall, `intl` extension is relatively new (PHP 5.3+) and I did find a couple of bugs myself which were quickly fixed within the next release.

What you could do is:

- [Submit](https://bugs.php.net/) a bug/feature request. There is a similar bug already [reported](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59430).
- Accept-Language format is really not that complex, I bet you could write your own parser within 20 lines of code. See [this article](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/use-accept-language-header) for an example.

Comment: It's 2017, and `Locale::acceptFromHttp` is still completely useless.