# php: how to translate my website using POEDIT and getttex?

Tags: php, poedit

Here is my source php code:

```
<? $locale = "en_EN";
if (isSet($_GET["locale"])) $locale = $_GET["locale"];
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<?php
echo _("Bonjour"); 
echo _("comment ça  va"); 
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I have created **locale/en_EN** folder where I have the **en.mo** and **en.po** files I have generated with POEdit.

Looks like I am missing a bridge between these mo files and my php script.

Any idea ?

Comment: What is POEDIR? You mean POEDIT?

Comment: yes of course: Poedit

Comment: It does not matter: whatever: it can be windows or linux.
Problem comes from PHP script, not from my OS.
(gettext extension is enabled)

Regards

Comment: It does, actually. Check this [SO POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398113/php-gettext-problems) regarding issues with gettext on Windows.