# PHP Localization Question

Tags: php, localization, gettext

I'm building a Open Source product and I thinking about Localization, I've read about [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) but there seems to be a lot of problem to get it to work in different systems (servers,os etc).

How would you handle this? Is there a secure way to help gettext work on several systems? Perhaps it already is?

Regards from Sweden / Tobias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at [**Zend_translate**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.translate.html), [**Zend_locale**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.locale.html) and [**Zend_Date**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.date.html). I'm only starting to dabble with them myself, but to me, they already look like a really good, clean and modern solution to internationalization, in contrast to the chaos that is gettext.

The introduction to Zend_translate lists a number of strong arguments why to choose it (or something similar) over gettext.

> In multilingual applications, the
>   content must be translated into
>   several languages and display content
>   depending on the user's language. PHP
>   offers already several ways to handle
>   such problems, however the PHP
>   solution has some problems:
>
> Inconsistent API: There is no single API for the different source
>   formats. The usage of gettext for
>   example is very complicated.
>
> PHP supports only gettext and native array: PHP itself offers only
>   support for array or gettext. All
>   other source formats have to be coded
>   manually, because there is no native
>   support.
>
> No detection of the default language: The default language of the
>   user cannot be detected without deeper
>   knowledge of the backgrounds for the
>   different web browsers.
>
> Gettext is not thread-safe: PHP's gettext library is not thread
>   safe, and it should not be used in a
>   multithreaded environment. This is due
>   to problems with gettext itself, not
>   PHP, but it is an existing problem.

Comment: I'm looking at it right now, seem a bit large perhaps. Do you now how, for example, Drupal and WordPress are doing this?

Comment: WP uses gettext: http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers I think Drupal has its own system, I don't know what it's based on: http://drupal.org/project/i18n It may seem a bit large but It's certainly one of the leanest and best solutions around. There isn't that much else on the market, check my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620670/i18n-with-gettext-but-without-the-locale-hassle

Comment: After I tested Zend_Locale & Translate I realize that it's just what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Zend Framework's [Zend_Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.using.html) is most flexible what I've seen. It doesn't necessarily need gettext support module in PHP's side as it reads the .mo-binary format itself.

Answer (score 0):

The language blocks should be kept external to the program. They may be in a database or in XML files. This will enable further languages to be added at a later point in time.

Then all your application needs to do is identify the localisation by the user and serve up the appropriate text for each situation.