# Whats the best way to do site translation files for a php site?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [what is the best way to put a translation system in php website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344383/what-is-the-best-way-to-put-a-translation-system-in-php-website)
>   [PHP Localization Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149116/php-localization-question)

Like my website i'm working on will be both English and French. I already have a language on file. So i was not sure how site translation files/systems are done.

Comment: Which itself is a dupe of [this older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149116/php-localization-question).  I think I might actually hit the close vote limit today, yikes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use google translation api instead of doing it manually. You get support for all languages. 
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=image#translate

Comment: Brilliant Idea.Why to re-Invent the wheel