# what is the most efficient way to make a multlingual website

Tags: php, zend-framework, translation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the best way to put a translation system in php website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344383/what-is-the-best-way-to-put-a-translation-system-in-php-website)

I am planning to use Zend translate.

Which  will be the efficient and easy way to develop a multi lingual webiste.

1. csv
2. array
3. xml
4. Any other option

Now we planning to add 3 languages. In future we may add other languages. So which way will be better to implement which will help to reduce changes in future

Comment: Whatever is easiest for you to maintain. The .mo/.po formats come with lovely pre-built [editing tools](http://www.poedit.net/); if you don't have end user translators, I guess any of the formats will do

Comment: *(reference)* [How to decide which translation adapter to use](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.adapter.html#zend.translate.adapter.decision)

Answer (score 0):

Zend Locale is a good start. Usually creating a website that is for multiple languages is more than just terminology changes, it's new formatting of numbers, time, currency, etc. I'd really look into implementing Zend Locale:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Gettext is very efficient and fast. Easy to add other languages and there is an open source online tool for contributing translations by other translators: http://glotpress.org

Answer (score 0):

This has already been discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228018/php-multilingual-site

If you dont want to go with a framework, i would personally suggest `XML` files since they are a lot easier to maintain and edit along the way, as compared to `CSV`'s