# Setting up gettext for php under ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, gettext

What I tried :

1. sudo apt-get install php-gettext
2. sudo apt-get install gettext
3. sudo apt-get install locales

My translation files (*.mo, *.po) are under `/usr/local/php/include/myapp/i18n/locale/` e.g
`/usr/local/php/include/myapp/i18n/locale/da_DK/LC_MESSAGES/generic.mo`

I have put /etc/php5/conf.d/gettext.ini

`extension=gettext.so`

apache2 restart gives me this error :

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/gettext.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/gettext.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

What  I am doing wrong ? As far as I remember this is standard way to install an extension under linux. This is working fine at my local system, but not on an amazon instance.

`php --version
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/gettext.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/gettext.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb 28 2014 23:14:25) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies`

please guide me to setup this extension on ubuntu.

Comment: yes I have done it already.

Comment: You could try `locate gettext.so` to see if it has been built in a different location. If so, try amending the directive in your php.ini file.

Comment: any reason to downvote ?

Comment: Also, are you sure `/etc/php4` is correct? You are using 5.3.x, not version 4.

Comment: I have cut-past from command line for php --version. its php5,that was typo sorry

Comment: `locate gettext.so` gives `/usr/lib/perl5/auto/Locale/gettext/gettext.so`

Comment: That's not going to be your PHP `gettext` module, since it is in a Perl folder - you might need to update your `locate` database. Did `apt-get install php-gettext` return any errors?

Comment: no error for php-gettext : `php-gettext is already the newest version.`

Comment: Alright, so you need to find out where `gettext` was built.

Comment: I tried `updatedb` and then `locate gettext.so` it give same output

Comment: Try uninstalling `php-gettext` and then reinstalling it?

Comment: `locate php-gettext` give `/usr/share/php/php-gettext
/usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.inc
/usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.php
/usr/share/php/php-gettext/streams.php
`

Comment: It seems its not installing gettext.so module instead its wrapper around gettext sth like that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So this mystery resolved by excellent [SOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541747/use-php-gettext-without-having-to-install-locales)

One of the [comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php#91187) for gettext on php.net says:

```
Warning for Linux (Ubuntu) users!  Your system will *only* support the locales installed on your OS, in the *exact* format given by your OS.  (See also the PHP setlocale man page.)  To get a list of them, enter locale -a, which will give you something like this:

C
en_US.utf8
ja_JP.utf8
POSIX

So this machine only has English and Japanese!  To add eg. Finnish, install the package:

sudo apt-get install language-pack-fi-base

Rerun locale -a, and "fi_FI.utf8" should appear.  Make sure you're using the same name in your PHP code:

setlocale(LC_ALL, "fi_FI.utf8");

Adjust your po paths so that they match, e.g. "./locale/fi_FI.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po".

Now restart Apache, and it should finally work.  Figuring this out took quite a while...
```

My issue resolved exactly by following these steps:

1. sudo apt-get install language-pack-da-base  (danish)
2. locale -a  (confirmed da_DK locale loaded)
3. <strike>mv da_DK da_DK.utf8  (renamed the locales dir)</strike>
   `bind_textdomain_codeset('messages', 'UTF8');`

   One of the debugging point for me was  `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'da_DK.utf8');` which was returning false for invalid/non-existent locales

What about gettext.so extension:

The php installation I got through apt-get seems to have the extension added during compilation 
 We can see if gettext is compiled module e.g  `php -m |grep gettext` , which seems to be true !
 I don't need [gettext.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gettext.installation.php), which is desired only when PHP is compiled  `--with-gettext=shared`, which is not the case here.

Comment: I've run into my fair share of issues setting up gettext for a variety of environments, namely on Ubuntu and in Windows on XAMPP (including the locale one here). I've documented them all in an article on my blog, for anyone who's still struggling with these issues: https://blog.terresquall.com/2020/09/troubleshooting-php-gettext/