# "locale -a" is different on server and PHP

Tags: php, locale, redhat, setlocale

I would like to use setlocale with "es_ES". It returns false, but other languages like "de_DE" are working fine.

So I checked "locale -a" on the server (Red Hat 4.4.6-4 ). It's on the list. When I use the following code in PHP it is not in the list:

```
<?php echo system('locale -a'); ?>
```

It returns different results then the server. Any ideas, how to add es for using the locale in PHP?

I am using Apache 2.2.15.

Comment: Please specify your webserver.

Comment: Apache 2.2.15 on Red Hat 4.4.6-4

Comment: I took the following workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541747/use-php-gettext-without-having-to-install-locales

Answer (score -1):

First try it again after you restart the apache2 server!!

I am using apache on ubuntu.
I can specify this in the /etc/apache2/envvars file, along with the PATH and other environment variables.

You should reload the HTTP server configuration files. (eg service apache2 reload)

Comment: You can specify the installed locales in an environment variable...!?

Comment: I think it isn't recommended, but that wasn't point.
The point is to change to a different installed locale.

Comment: Well, no, seriously: if there's an environment variable that can change the output of `locale -a`, by all means please tell us in detail.

Comment: $ cat /etc/apache2/envvars

 ...

 ## The locale used by some modules like mod_dav
 export LANG=C
 ## Uncomment the following line to use the system default locale instead:
 #. /etc/default/locale

 export LANG